# What kind of cheese is the result of boiling milk with vinegar at home?

Tags: cheese, cheese-making

With this recipe http://www.wikihow.com/Make-Cheese-at-Home, which out of the following required cheese will I get at home?
http://www.food.com/recipe/incredibly-delicious-cheese-garlic-bread-spread-18914

Comment: You will get paneer or chhena, I think you know those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The resultant cheese in your first link will be a fresh, soft cheese, nothing like either of the Parmesan or cheddar cheeses mentioned in your second link.  It is also an acid-based cheese, not a made with either rennet or bacterial cultures as are most other cheeses.

Parmesan is a very long aged cheese.

Cheddar is a... well... cheddared cheese (cheddaring is a process which reduces the moisture content of the curds) that is then aged for varying periods of time.

The fresh cheese in your first link will not serve you well in the same roles as either Parmesan or Cheddar.  While I realize these products may not be available easily where you live, they are very distinctive and hard to substitute for with homemade products--they just also not the kind of cheese that is normally made at home.

The home made cheese described is most similar to an unaged feta (although not goat's milk), or a Mexican queso fresco.

Comment: That's very sad. So, I have no choice other than looking for those cheese in market for making "cheese spread"? Cheese spread made from fresh home made cheese will not taste great?

Comment: I won't say it will be bad, but it will be different.

Comment: can this cheese do instead?  http://www.zopnow.com/pizza-cheese-mozzarella-v-1-kg-p.php

Comment: @AnishaKaul The home made acid paneer will be different than pizza cheese.  It will not have the long stringiness or the same melting characteristics, although it may be similar in that the primary flavor is a mild dairiness.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9276994#9276994

Comment: What about mozzarella?

Comment: The pizza cheese is a type of low-moisture mozerella.

Comment: So, can that be used?

Comment: You can use it, but again, it is going to be a very different result.